# Mockito BodyInserters.fromValue with webClient method post

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, webclient

I am trying to figure out how to perform the test webclient metodo post with mockito.
I can't find a solution to have a minimum acceptable test to pass.

Here is my code:

CallApiRest:

```
CallApiRest
@Autowired
    private CallApiConfig apiConfig;


    /**
     * Search for patient existence in Faro
     * @param dataPatient request data patient
     * @return String
     */
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> findPatient(Map<String, String> dataPatient) {
        log.info("Entrando en el apiRest haciendo la llamada a faro");

        return  apiConfig.webClient().post()
                            .uri("/login")
                            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(dataPatient))
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {})
                            .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class, CallApiRest::statusCode)
                            .block();
    }

    /**
     * We control the error codes to pass it later to Frontend.
     * @param e exception parameter
     * @return the error or return the value of body
     */
    public static Mono<? extends Map<String, Object>> statusCode(WebClientResponseException e) {
        try {
            log.info("Comprobamos el resultado de la consulta si hay errores, ya sea por cuerpo vacio o datos del paciente erroneos.");
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            if (e.getRawStatusCode() == 403) {
                return Mono.just(objectMapper.readValue(e.getResponseBodyAsString(), new TypeReference<>() {
                        }));
            } else {
                return Mono.error(e);
            }
        } catch (JsonProcessingException jsonEx) {
            log.error("Error en el servicio apiRest Json: CallApiRest");
            return Mono.error(jsonEx);
        }
    }
```

CallApiConfig

```
@Configuration
public class CallApiConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(){
        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("http://urlok")
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();
    }
}
```

TEST:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CallApiRestTest {

    @Mock
    private WebClient webClient;
    @Mock
    private WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriSpec ;
    @Mock
    private WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBodySpec ;
    @Mock
    private WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpec ;
    @Mock
    private WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec ;
    @Mock
    private CallApiConfig apiConfig;
    @InjectMocks
    private CallApiRest callApiRest;

    //Initial variables
    private Map<String, String> dataPatient;

    private Map<String, Object> dataResponse;
    private Map<String, Object> dataResponseError;

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private String statusOnError;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        dataPatient = new HashMap<>();
        dataResponse = new HashMap<>();
        dataResponseError = new HashMap<>();
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        //initialize dataPatient
        dataPatient.put("identificationNumber", "XXXX");
        dataPatient.put("birthdate","XXXX");
        dataPatient.put("allowPatientData", "true");
        dataPatient.put("appointmentId","XXX");

        //Initialize dataResponse status->200 ok
        dataResponse.put("personalData", "XXX");
        dataResponse.put("am", "XXX");
        dataResponse.put("gdpr", "XXX");

        //Initialize dataResponse status->403 Bad_request (Forbidden)
        dataResponseError.put("error", "Error 8.");

        //Initialize data statusOnError JsonParse
        statusOnError= """
                {\r
                 "status": 200,\r
                 "message": "ok"\r
                 }""";

    }

    @Test
    void findPatientOk() throws IOException {

        //when
        when(apiConfig.webClient()).thenReturn(webClient);
        when(requestBodyUriSpec.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
        when(requestBodySpec.header(any(),any())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
        when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
        when(requestBodySpec.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
        when(requestBodySpec.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
        when(requestBodySpec.body(BodyInserters.fromValue(dataPatient))).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
        when(requestHeadersSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
        when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {})).thenReturn(Mono.just(dataResponse));
        when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {}).onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class, CallApiRest::statusCode))
                .thenReturn(Mono.just(objectMapper.readValue(statusOnError, new TypeReference<>() {
                })));

        //given
        Map<String, Object> response = callApiRest.findPatient(dataPatient);


        //then
        assertTrue(response.containsKey("personalData"));
        assertNotNull(response);
    }
```

ERROR:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'body' method:
    requestBodySpec.body(
    org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters$$Lambda$458/0x0000000800ef7ab8@a92be4f
);

 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. requestBodySpec.body(
    org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters$$Lambda$458/0x0000000800ef7ab8@6edcad64
);

Typically, stubbing argument mismatch indicates user mistake when writing tests.
Mockito fails early so that you can debug potential problem easily.
However, there are legit scenarios when this exception generates false negative signal:
  - stubbing the same method multiple times using 'given().will()' or 'when().then()' API
    Please use 'will().given()' or 'doReturn().when()' API for stubbing.
  - stubbed method is intentionally invoked with different arguments by code under test
    Please use default or 'silent' JUnit Rule (equivalent of Strictness.LENIENT).
For more information see javadoc for PotentialStubbingProblem class.
```

I don't understand it well, and the little documentation that exists does not include methods with BodyInserters and onErrorResume.

I would appreciate some help, thanks.

I need it to pass the test without errors, it is only a simulated request, in which the data I receive is 200 ok.